# git pull hangs after authentication

Tags: git, ssh, repository, bitbucket

I have a repo on bitbucket with a project. I want to have the current up-to-date version on a server in my local network.
I connect to that server via `ssh` and I do a `git pull`. Git works trough ssh.

After I enter my password, it hangs with the cursor blinking. If I enter a wrong password I get a `fatal: Authentication failed`.

If I do a clone of the same repo in another directory, and then I do a pull, it works.

Someone with whom I work made a "backup" of the entire folder (cp) and moved the folders around a bit. Would that break some stuff?

I don't want to manually pick the stuff from the production version that's not inside the bitbucket repo and put it back.

Comment: Is there any process in the server that could prevents the `git pull` to update files when done in the `prod` directory? (as opposed to the `git push` done still on the server, but on another git repo clone)

Comment: What `git status` and `git branch -a` return in your prod repo?

Comment: Could you show a diff between the `.git/config` files from the working and non-working clones

Comment: Status is up to date.
git branch -a:   
`remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`
`remotes/origin/master`
`remotes/origin/production-fix`
.
@BenGraham no differences between the configs :(

Comment: How about a `diff -qr` on your two clones. There must be _some_ difference causing this. Your working clone is on the same machine right? You haven't just got a broken `~/.ssh/config` on the non-working one? Also, try `ssh -v user@hostname` to origin. Debugging at the SSH level may be helpful.

Comment: The clones were on the same machine.
In the end I decided to copy manually the ignored files (the DB and some other stuff) in the working clone. I'm aware it's not the most elegant solution, but I didn't had a choice - my boss was pressing me.

I don't have the broken clone anymore so I can't answer your question, Ben.

Anyway, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I do a clone of the same repo in another directory, and then I do a pull, it works.

and

> I don't want to manually pick the stuff from the production version that's not inside the bitbucket repo and put it back.

suggestion/workaround: get a working clone from bitbucket, add your broken production repo as a remote, pull from that remote and push back to bitbucket.